# Call overriden method from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is there a way to call overriden method from the base class?

```
class SpaceObject {
  public draw() {}
}
class Sun : SpaceObject{
  public draw() {}
}

Sun planet1 = new Sun();
SpaceObject planet2 = new SpaceObject();
SpaceObject planet3 = new SpaceObject();

List<SpaceObject> objs = new List<SpaceObject>();
objs.Add(planet1);
objs.Add(planet2);
objs.Add(planet3);

foreach(SpaceObject o in objs)
  o.draw();
```

Is there a way so that in foreach for planet1 there will be call on `Sun::Draw()` instead of `SpaceObject::Draw()` ?

Right now I have it this way

```
foreach(SpaceObject o in objs)
  if(o.GetType() == typeof(Sun) ((Sun)o).draw();
  else o.draw();
```

But I plan to have multiple inheritances of `SpaceObject` so this is not a good way to go.

Comment: Virtual keyword? Edit: ok, in c++ you can use the virtual keyword in front of your method declaration to denote that you must climb as higher as you can in the hierarchy when faced with collections of polimorphic stuff. I know this is C# but maybe it's the same? Try "public virtual void draw" for each one of them.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan c# also virtual is virtual only.. be sure..

Comment: @Buksy: `SpaceObject` will have `virtual public void draw()` and `Sun` will have `public override void draw()`. This is elementary OOP, you should stop coding and read up a bit first in order to avoid getting stuck every 5 minutes.

Comment: Read what said above. Real C# people can help. Seems different from C++. @Sriram Sakthivel, got it. override keyword then it is.

Comment: @Buksy: You need to make the `Sun` implementation `override`. Right now it's [shadowing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172785%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the base method.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan Don't take me wrong. I said you're correct.. You can be sure saying *use virtual*. You got me? :)

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, no problem man. I am sorry if I wrote something that came out sounding different from what I thought :). I have never written a single line of C#, I thought I'd just give it a try :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the `SpaceObject.Draw()` method `virtual`, that way you can give the `Sun` an `override Draw()` method. For more info you might want to look at [This link on the Microsoft pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) to learn more about the topic of inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `SpaceObject` and `Sun` class this way

```
    class SpaceObject
    {
        public virtual void draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Log from parent");
        }
    }

    class Sun : SpaceObject
    {
        public override void draw()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Log from Child");
        }
    }
```

And you do not need the `if` checking and type casting. Just call

```
o.draw();
```